# Происходи не правильный запуск сборки в android studio

Tags: android-studio

Я абсолютный чайник. Установил Андроид Студио установил все необходимые SDK. Запускаю сборку на виртуальном устройстве, надпись на экране my application. Запускаю на реальном уст-ве: my application. Скидываю вручную с ноута на телефона. Устанавливаю. Всё работает. Я даже понять не могу где мой косяк. Такое чувство что андроид студио даже не пытается установить билд. Поясните где я не прав и что делать...
Windows 11

Comment: Проблема не очень понятна. Судя по описанию у вас во всех случаях запускается успешно приложение. У вас проблема в том, что оно как-то иначе выглядит в разных случаях?

Comment: Я просто перетаскиваю сборку(тем временем это полноценное рабочее приложение) в андроид студио. Из папки в окно. Пытаюсь ее запустить. Открывается эмулятор. И во весь экран My application. Вместо приложения надпись.

Comment: Т.е. вы не из исходников собираете, а из APK? Тут, насколько я знаю, просто сделать не получится - надо много дней крутому спецу ковыряться чтобы всё заработало. Какая у вас конечная цель? Может быть вы не тем путём её достичь пытаетесь? Я много лет под андроид код пишу и ни разу не возникало необходимости APK запускать таким образом.